# Multiple line parsing within bash

Tags: bash, awk

I'm having trouble parsing a multiple line file. I've tried with `awk` but I only know how to do it with single lines.

The files contains records like this:

```
0123456789ab    "(channel
  (1
    (saturation(14))
  )
  (2
    (saturation(41))
  )
  (3
    (saturation(25))
  )
  (4
    (saturation(27))
  )
  (5
    (saturation(33))
    (ssid
      (0
        (ssid(TestingAlpha))
        (rssi(5))
      )
    )
  )
  (6
    (saturation(100))
    (ssid
      (0
        (ssid(TestingBravo))
        (rssi(70))
      )
      (1
        (ssid(TestingCharlie))
        (rssi(44))
      )
    )
  )
  (7
    (saturation(40))
  )
  (8
    (saturation(22))
  )
  (9
    (saturation(19))
  )
  (10
    (saturation(20))
  )
  (11
    (saturation(11))
  )
  (12
  )
  (13
    (saturation(11))
  )
)
"
```

It's a wireless survey. Any output that can be analyzed (database records, excel columns, etc) is acceptable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232843/jq-or-xsltproc-alternative-for-s-expressions

Comment: Using a trad Lisp format instead of JSON is Hacker News crazy. See also https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/oon44/sexpressions_the_fatfree_alternative_to_json/

Comment: I'm googing for how to use Awk to parse sexp and so far drawing a blank. It's not particularly hard if your format is this simple, but you need to store the results in memory until you reach the end.

Comment: one way is to remove all newlines and parse it as one huge line, i.e use `tr -d '\n`

Comment: This is butt-ugly but turns your example into almost-JSON: `sed -e 's/(\([0-9][0-9]*\))/ \1/g' -e 's/(\([A-Za-z][A-Za-z]*\))/ "\1"/g' -e 's/(\([0-9a-z][0-9a-z]*\)/{"\1":/g' -e 's/)/},/g'`

Comment: Awk is very efficient at processing tabular data. Here you have kind of a tree data structure. Awk won't fit. You could try to transform data into a more common tree data format such as xml or json. Your can also have a look at Lisp, as it's full of parenthesis :)

Comment: You need a context-free grammar to recognize an S-expression, and regular expressions simply aren't up to the task.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comment, Awk is very efficient at processing tabular data. Here you have kind of a tree data structure. Awk won't fit.

However because the format seems stable, we can cheat a bit :

```
BEGIN {
    OFS=";"
    print "bizid", "ssid", "channel", "saturation", "rssi"
}

NR == 1 {
    split($1,A," ")
    bizid=A[1]
    next
}

{
    level = length($1) / 2
}

function clearv(v,      R) {
    split(v,R,")")
    return R[1]
}

level == 1 {
    channel=$2
    next
}

level == 2 && $2 == "saturation" {
    saturation=clearv($3)
    next
}

level == 4 && $2 == "ssid" {
    ssid=clearv($3)
    next
}

level == 4 && $2 == "rssi" {
    print bizid, ssid, channel, saturation, clearv($3)
    next
}
```

produces :

```
bizid;ssid;channel;saturation;rssi
0123456789ab;TestingAlpha;5;33;5
0123456789ab;TestingBravo;6;100;70
0123456789ab;TestingCharlie;6;100;44
```

which seems acceptable for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be debugged (not by me!) but here's how to approach the problem: write a recursive function that just descends every time it hits "(", build up an array indexed by the current depth of the calls at that time, and print that array contents when you hit the last ")" in the string:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="[)]\\s*\"\\s*" }
function descend(tail) {
    if ( ++depth == 30 ) {
        print "ERROR: went too deep" | "cat>&2"
        exit 1
    }
    while ( match(tail,/([^()]+)([()])(.*)/,a) ) {
        val[depth] = gensub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"","g",a[1])
        if ( a[2] == "(" ) {
            descend(a[3])
        }
        else {
            for (i=1; i<=depth; i++) {
                printf "%s,", val[i]
            }
            print ""
        }
        tail = a[3]
    }
    --depth
}
{ sub(/^[^"]+"[(]/,""); descend($0) }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
channel,1,saturation,14,
channel,1,saturation,,
channel,1,saturation,,2,saturation,41,
channel,1,saturation,,2,saturation,,
channel,1,saturation,,2,saturation,,3,saturation,25,
channel,1,saturation,,2,saturation,,3,saturation,,
channel,1,saturation,,2,saturation,,3,saturation,,4,saturation,27,
channel,1,saturation,,2,saturation,,3,saturation,,4,saturation,,
channel,1,saturation,,2,saturation,,3,saturation,,4,saturation,,5,saturation,33,
channel,1,saturation,,2,saturation,,3,saturation,,4,saturation,,5,saturation,,ssid,0,ssid,TestingAlpha,
channel,1,saturation,,2,saturation,,3,saturation,,4,saturation,,5,saturation,,ssid,0,ssid,,rssi,5,
channel,1,saturation,,2,saturation,,3,saturation,,4,saturation,,5,saturation,,ssid,0,ssid,,rssi,,
channel,1,saturation,,2,saturation,,3,saturation,,4,saturation,,5,saturation,,ssid,0,ssid,,rssi,,
channel,1,saturation,,2,saturation,,3,saturation,,4,saturation,,5,saturation,,ssid,0,ssid,,rssi,,
channel,1,saturation,,2,saturation,,3,saturation,,4,saturation,,5,saturation,,ssid,0,ssid,,rssi,,6,saturation,100,
channel,1,saturation,,2,saturation,,3,saturation,,4,saturation,,5,saturation,,ssid,0,ssid,,rssi,,6,saturation,,ssid,0,ssid,TestingBravo,
ERROR: went too deep
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and gensub().

I do really like the idea of converting it to JSON and then using `jq` on it instead though, just not something I'm familiar enough with JSON or jq to tackle.